# How do I add a visualforce page to an out-of-the-box page for Lead details?

Tags: apex, visualforce, page-layout, leads

I have developed a visualforce page + controller that fetches and displays data from a  back end REST server for a given lead.

How do I add this page to the lead details page layout so that everyone,who can see the lead, can see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `Standard Controller` and an extension.

**Markup**

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="MyExtension">
```

**Code**

```
public with sharing class MyExtension
{
    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
    }
}
```

The extension itself is optional, but if you want to include your page as a custom button or on the Layout, you absolutely must use the appropriate `standardController` attribute on your `<apex:page>` tag. See also: [Use Visualforce Pages in Page Layouts and Mobile Cards](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/visualforce_mobile_salesforce1/units/visualforce_mobile_salesforce1_layouts_cards)